# In Laravel Eloquent create method I am not able to save the data in database

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have Three models:

- `Language`
- `Article`
- `Category`

The `Article` table has two foreign keys `category_id` and `Language_id`. Language-Model has "One to Many" Relationship with Article-Model, Similarly Category-Model has "One to Many" Relationship with Article-Model.

My `Category` model:

```
class Category extends Model
            { 

            protected $fillable = [
                 'category_name', 
            ];

            public function articles(){

                return $this->hasMany('App\Article');
             }
           }
```

My `Language` model:

```
class Language extends Model
    {
         protected $fillable = [
            'language_name'
        ];

         public function articles(){

            return $this->hasMany('App\Article');
        }

    }
```

My `Article` model:

```
class Article extends Model
{
 protected $fillable = [

   'language_id','category_id','category_name','article_title',
   'article_desc','source_from','source_url','video_link',
   'audio_url','author_name','article_image_url','like_count'
    ];

    public function languages(){

        return $this->belongsTo('App\Language');
    }

    public function categories(){

        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
    }

}
```

How can I insert in the database using Laravel Eloquent?

```
 $Article = new Article (
                 [
                   'article_image_url' => $img_url ,
                   'audio_url' => $audio_url,
                   'category_name'=>$category_name ,
                   'article_title'=>$request->article_title,
                   'article_desc'=>$request->article_desc,
                   'source_from'=>$request->source_from,
                    'source_url'=>$request->source_url,
                    'video_link'=>$request->video_link,
                    'author_name'=>$request->author_name,
                    'like_count'=>'0',

                  ]
            );

            $language = new Language;
            $category = new Category;
            $language->articles()->save($Article);
```

`language_id` doesn't have a default value; it is foreign key.

Comment: I think you have to save the languaje first, then make the relation as you do in the last line, by the way you have and attribute "category_name" in your article model, you are duplicating it, it belongs to category model

Comment: what kind of error do you get?

Comment: @robbyrr this is the error i m getting  "General error: 1364 Field 'category_id' doesn't have a default value"-- since they are two foreign key for the article model category_id & language_id i m not able to create a row in article model. if table has one foreign i can create using this command  $language->articles()->save($Article).

Comment: It's because you don't pass along a category_id..it doesnt get an id from instantiating it alone. Same goes for language_id...if you dd($category->id) you probably get null..You have to get  them from Request or route-model binding